# Spring - how to connect to database mysql

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to connect to the mysql database, but to no avail. I put the dependencies of mysql and spring boot start jdbc and jpa.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SA7Jh.png)

I added the following lines to aplciation.properties.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springone 
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

I'm using the xampp and the door is 3306.

When I run the project, a lot appears on the console. I took a print from the end.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Etd6r.png)

I'm using the visual studio code editor

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springone?serverTimezone=UTC
```

instead of

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springone
```

Comment: It ran but a login page appears and I can't access another page.

Comment: Well, that error has nothing to do with your question, you just fixed one issue, and moved to another. I suggest you open a new stackoverflow question for a different issue. You are welcome.

Comment: Thank you men, i'll do this